# How to delete taxonomy term when a wordpress user is removed?

Tags: wordpress

i need to Delete wp_terms -> name field when a user is removed .

my requirement is admin needs to assign posts to specific users, that is admin need to add a post to user1 ,but user2 should not see that.for this i created a custom post and add taxonomy for that.And the terms are users Usernames .so i need to list the usernames of the users as terms in the taxonomy.when a new user is registered his username should updated in the wp_terms table also,so i will get the usernames as terms. this is working well ,now i need to delete the term from taxonomy when the user is removed.

i stucked here .please suggest some solution for this

what i have done is

```
add_action( 'delete_user', 'yg_user_delete', 10, 1 );

function yg_user_delete( $user_id ) {

$user_info = get_userdata($user_id); $user_name = $user_info->user_login;
print_r($user_info);


wp_delete_term( $user_name, 'user1', array() );

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got the solution

```
add_action( 'delete_user', 'yg_user_delete', 10, 1 );

function yg_user_delete( $user_id ) {

$user_info = get_userdata($user_id); 
$user_name = $user_info->user_login;

wp_delete_term( get_term_by('name', $user_name, 'user1')->term_id, 'user1',    array() );

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with your code.
The main issue is `wp_delete_term` requires a `term_id` not a `term_name`.
You can use `wp_get_object_terms` to get the `term_id` for the user.

I haven't tested this code but it should point you in the right direction.

```
function delete_user_terms( $user_id ) {
    $taxonomy = 'user1'; // Change this.

    $terms = wp_get_object_terms( $user_id, $taxonomy ); // Get the terms for this user.
    if ( is_wp_error( $terms ) ) {
        return; // Taxonomy does not exist.
    }

    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        wp_delete_term( $term->term_id, $taxonomy ); // This requires Term ID. Not term name.
    }
}
add_action( 'delete_user', 'delete_user_terms', 10, 1 );
```

Comment: Whats your taxonomy called?

Comment: my taxonomy name is user1

Comment: i got the solution and i posted above